# How to remove CSS attribute such that HTML attribute will take effect again?

Tags: css

I've got this HTML:

```
<td align="right">$12</td>
```

But the text isn't right-aligned because somewhere in the stylesheet it says

```
td { text-align: left; }
```

I can override this style further down by doing something like this:

```
.bugnote table td, .bugnote table th {
    text-align: inherit;
}
```

But "inherit" doesn't have the effect I was hoping for: to clear the attribute. It's still left-aligned. Is there a way to essentially remove/clear any previously set `text-align` attributes?

Comment: @Michas: Nothing is preventing me, but I don't like using JS for styling, and I don't think it's worth the effort. I'd rather leave it misaligned than use JS.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, You have some CSS and some HTML You are not able to edit?

Comment: @Michas: I've got a default stylesheet which applies the `text-align:left` to everything. I can extend the CSS with my own. The HTML is generated; I can't alter that without digging into the library which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inherit` means that the element will assume the style of its parent.

You can't "clear" existing style specifications, so you'll have to override it with your desired result.  Ex:

```
.bugnote table td, .bugnote table th {
    text-align: right;
}
```

If your browser support requirements allow it, you could refine the selector to use CSS2's attribute selector.  Ex:

```
.bugnote table td[align="right"], .bugnote table th[align="right"] {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's no other indicators that the text should be right-aligned except for that `align="right"` so there's nothing else for me to hook in to. Not *all* tables `.bugnote table td`s should be right-aligned.

Comment: If your browser support requirements allow it, you could refine the selector to use CSS3's attribute selector.  `td[align="right"]` I think.

Comment: Yes. I came to that same conclusion myself. The attribute selector works well enough for my needs.

Comment: That attribute selector [is in CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use obsolete attributes.

Instead, use `style="text-align: right;"` on the table cell like you're supposed to. Inline `style` attributes override styles defined in a stylesheet.

Comment: ...this isn't an answer. I'd happily use CSS if I could, but this is generated markup that I can't alter.

Comment: @Mark: What generates it? The `align` attribute has been deprecated for a long time, and is no longer supported in HTML5. I'm sure it's possible to modify this to work *properly*, you're just trying to find a way to avoid that. Right?

Comment: @animuson: PHP Markdown Extra generates it. I'm sure I could modify the script if I really needed to, but then I can't upgrade the script. I'm not overly concerned about deprecated tags. I got tired of the purist game. Might not be in the HTML5 spec, but it doesn't look like browsers have dropped it yet. http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/YudzB/

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
.bugnote [align=right] {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Browser support is probably not all there, but that's OK. It's for an internal site anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please never use any style attribute like `align="right"`. As you noticed, it's evil. Also try to avoid inline-styles as much as possible.  Use clean css, and you won't run into those troubles.

**Edit:**

You can try improving your [selector specifity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) and/or use the !important keyword.

Comment: The HTML is generated; I can't alter it. Hence why I'm asking this question.

Comment: The specificity isn't the problem. `text-align: inherit;` simply doesn't do what I want, and there doesn't seem to be any other value that does.

Comment: every css-style has a standard value. The browser applies it automatically, when no styles are present. In european languages `text-align` has default value `left`. So it makes no sense to "clear" the value. You need to assign the value you want, either `left`, `center` or `right`.

Comment: @Mark and of course this has no effect, because `text-align:inherit;`applies the style from the parent element, which is by standard `left`. So just take `text-align:right` and you're fine.

Comment: I get why inherit doesn't work. And I can't "just take `text-align:right`" because I have nothing to apply it to. The only thing distinct about that table cell is that it has the attribute `align="right"`. There aren't any other CSS classes I can hook into. Hence the problem. It's okay though; CSS2.1's attribute selectors work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.bugnote table td, .bugnote table th').css('text-align','none')});
```

Comment: See discussion under question; I'd prefer not to use JS. You also left out the fact you're using jQuery (had I not known better, this wouldn't work). Lastly, this *still* doesn't have the desired effect, because I specifically wanted the `align="right"` attribute to decide the alignment, not that selector. (To fix it we just have to add `[align=right]`, but I can do that in CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Katie's solution didn't work for me so I overrode the markdown table filter.

app/tables.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
    tables
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Process Tables (add default 'left' alignment and inline styles)
"""

from flask.ext.markdown import Extension
from markdown.extensions.tables import TableProcessor, etree

class BSTableProcessor(TableProcessor):
    """ Process Tables in a Bootstrap compatible way """
    def _build_row(self, row, parent, align, border):
        """ Given a row of text, build table cells. """
        tr = etree.SubElement(parent, 'tr')
        tag = 'td'
        if parent.tag == 'thead':
            tag = 'th'
        cells = self._split_row(row, border)
        # We use align here rather than cells to ensure every row
        # contains the same number of columns.
        for i, a in enumerate(align):
            c = etree.SubElement(tr, tag)
            try:
                c.text = cells[i].strip()
            except IndexError:
                c.text = ""

            a = (a or 'left')
            c.set('style', "text-align: %s;" % a)

class TableExtension(Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        """ Add an instance of TableProcessor to BlockParser. """
        md.parser.blockprocessors.add(
            'table', BSTableProcessor(md.parser), '<hashheader')
```

app/**init**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
    app
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Provides the flask application
"""

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.markdown import Markdown
from app.tables import TableExtension


def create_app():
    """Create webapp instance"""

    # Flask application
    app = Flask(__name__)
    md = Markdown(app)
    md.register_extension(TableExtension)

    # Views
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('markdowned.html')

    return app
```